# Что происходит, если GOPATH содержит больше 1 директории?

Tags: golang

Допустим в системе установлен go по дефолту, как описано в документации. И GOPATH - это директория, к примеру, ~/gocode/.
Теперь пользователь выкачивает проект, который написан на нескольких языках, включая go. Допустим, проект живет в ~/project/ (- это корень проекта) и подпроект написанный на go в ~/project/go-sub-project/
И вот если я в GOPATH добавлю ~/project/go-sub-project/ как второй воркспейс, то как два воркспеса будут себя вести? Каждый воркспейс изолирован от другого и ничего о др вокспейсх не знает? Конфликтов с зависимостями не будет? Может быть еще какие-то подводные камни?
**Update:**
В общем мой вывод, что лучше несколькими воркспейсами не пользоваться, а временно переопределять GOPATH при сборке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько путей можно добавить в GOPATH (в линуксе это делается через двоеточие). Ничего не взрывается. Но вот только похоже, что go берет исключительно первый путь, а все остальные игнорирует. Поэтому, если работать в первом проекте все будет как ожидается. Если работать в втором - будет ругаться, что не нашло библиотек или других файлов.
**Update:**
По-поводу 2-го воркспейса не все так однозначно. Если комманды go build, go install выполнять из директории проекта (который во 2-ом воркспейсе), то они работают с этим воркспейсом. Но вот комманда go get устанавливает стороннюю библиотеку в первый воркспейс. При этом при сборке проекта из 2-го воркспейса эта библиотека (из 1-го) используется.

Comment: Вопрос не в том можно ли добавлять два воркспейса, а есть ли какие-то сайд эффекты от этого.

Comment: тогда  ответ прост - сайд эффект прост - будет работать только первый путь в списке.

Comment: во 2-ом воркспейсе тоже можно работать, если его текущей директорией сделать

Comment: спасибо за подсказку